# User Authentication using RADIUS

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc-4, radius

I am wanting to authenticate users by using a RADIUS server in my MVC4 application.

We have an **SMTP, port #, and shared secret**.  However, I have not idea how to implement these into the application.

How would I go about implementing such information?  Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Radius isn't appropriate in this case - it's meant for physical network security: to authenticate Wi-Fi users on a corporate network, or when someone plugs a computer into an Ethernet switch. Also, Radius has nothing to do with SMTP.

Radius itself doesn't provide authentication - invariably there's some kind of back-end database. Microsoft's "NAP" Radius server uses Active Directory (an implementation of LDAP) for this, for example.

If you're using ASP.NET, then you might as well query Active Directory directly (see `System.DirectoryServices`). Also note that ASP.NET comes with the `ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider` class which does all of the work for you.

Otherwise, we need more information about what you want to accomplish, exactly.

Comment: Apologies for the ambiguity.  I'll look into the ASP.NET features you mentioned.